# How To Encode a Flash Parameter in Python

Tags: python, flash, encoding

I'm trying to generate an embeded flash widget on a page with Python using a dynamic parameter. Here's the code I currently have...

```
<embed src='http://musiclibre.org/dark_player' width='200' height='500' wmode='transparent' flashVars='http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=39d7e59de5284e033c7019e12f02467b&artist={{query}}&autoplay=1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'/>
```

The {{query}} parameter is passed through as a URL parameter. I'm not very technical, but I think the query value needs to be encoded for the flash to work. How do I encode the flash parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The `flashvars` are encoded as a standard URL [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You can use Python's [urllib.parse](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/urllib.parse.html) module to easily convert your string into this format.

From Flash you can access `flashvars` using the `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters` dictionary (`Application.application.parameters` if you are using an older SDK).

Comment: Thanks! Can someone show me the exact code I would use to make this change? I'm new to all of this.